# Rearrange the array of objects with id and parentid

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays. Both contain the objects with unique id and parentid values (given id's are just for example, in real they are generated by uuid generator).
The first one is ordered in the way that objects with parentid different than "parent" are situated right after the parent object with the corresponding id:

```
const array1 = [
  { id: "id1", parentId: "parent" },
  { id: "id2", parentId: "id1" },
  { id: "id3", parentId: "id2" },
  { id: "id4", parentId: "id3" },
  { id: "id5", parentId: "id4" },
  { id: "id6", parentId: "parent" },
  { id: "id7", parentId: "id6" },
  { id: "id8", parentId: "id7" },
  { id: "id9", parentId: "parent" }
];
```

The second one is sorted by "depth" of nesting:

```
const array2 = [
    { id: "id1", parentId: "parent" },
    { id: "id6", parentId: "parent" },
    { id: "id9", parentId: "parent" },
    { id: "id2", parentId: "id1" },
    { id: "id7", parentId: "id6" },
    { id: "id3", parentId: "id2" },
    { id: "id8", parentId: "id7" },
    { id: "id4", parentId: "id3" },
    { id: "id5", parentId: "id4" },
  ];
```

What is the best way to rearrange array2 to array1 order?

Comment: what about `{ id: "id2", parentId: "id2" },` looks like a circular reference.

Comment: Right, just fixed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with the `Array.prototype.reduce()` function

```js
const array2 = [
    { id: "id1", parentId: "parent" },
    { id: "id6", parentId: "parent" },
    { id: "id9", parentId: "parent" },
    { id: "id2", parentId: "id1" },
    { id: "id7", parentId: "id6" },
    { id: "id3", parentId: "id2" },
    { id: "id8", parentId: "id7" },
    { id: "id4", parentId: "id3" },
    { id: "id5", parentId: "id4" },
  ];
  
  const sortedArray2= array2.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    let item = accumulator.find(x => x.id === currentValue.parentId);
    let index = accumulator.indexOf(item);
    index = index !== -1 ? index + 1 : accumulator.length;
    accumulator.splice(index, 0, currentValue);
    return accumulator;
  }, []);
  
  console.log(sortedArray2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a helper function that does the variety of comparison that `sort` needs.

```
const sortHelper = (a,b)=>a>b?1:a<b?-1:0;
```

then just write

```
array2.sort((a,b) => sortHelper(a.id,b.id);
```

That is asking the `sort` function to use the function you provide to put the items into order. The function given here compares the values of the `id` property of each object.

Answer (score 0):

A single sort does not work, because of the parent children relation which is not respected while sorting the data.

This works in two parts:

1. Build a tree with the given relationship.
2. Traverse the tree by using a [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), level by level, using a stack and get sorted flat data back.

```js
var data = [{ id: "id1", parentId: "parent" }, { id: "id2", parentId: "id1" }, { id: "id3", parentId: "id2" }, { id: "id4", parentId: "id3" }, { id: "id5", parentId: "id4" }, { id: "id6", parentId: "parent" }, { id: "id7", parentId: "id6" }, { id: "id8", parentId: "id7" }, { id: "id9", parentId: "parent" }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            o[a.id] = { data: a, children: o[a.id] && o[a.id].children };
            o[a.parentId] = o[a.parentId] || {};
            o[a.parentId].children = o[a.parentId].children || [];
            o[a.parentId].children.push(o[a.id]);
        });
        return o[root].children;
    }(data, 'parent'),
    stack = [tree],
    result = [];

while (stack.length) {
    stack.shift().forEach(({ data, children = [] }) => {
        result.push(data);
        stack.push(children);
    });
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```